# How to mark that a question has been solved?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I'm new here. I have posted a question here 
[Question about n-simplex and its face](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734637/question-about-n-simplex-and-its-face)

And it has been solved, but I don't now how to mark a question indicating that it has been solved.

Comment: See [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only mechanism to mark a question as "solved" is for you to accept an answer. This is because Stack Exchange exists as a Q&A site, so the only reason we'd want to mark that a question has been adequately handled is that it's been given an adequate answer.

In the given case, since no one has written an answer, I would recommend either that you write an answer yourself or encourage someone who left a helpful comment to do so. Then, when the question has an answer, you can accept it.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer, Milo :)